# Can we set additional many to many on tables which already are one to many?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables in DB: users and adds. I set it as one to many because one user can publish many adds, and one add can be made by one user only. But now I need to set "favourites" feature. I suppose that I need to involvwe add_id to User. In that case, one user can have many favourites, but also one add can be favourited by many users. So I need join table. But can I do that if I already set them as one to many (one user -> many adds)?

This is User class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "users")
private List<Ads> ads;
```

and this is Add class:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private JwtUser users;
```

Comment: Please do not post code as images. It is hard to read even for those with good eye sight, useless for people who are blind and you can't cut and past from them to reuse in comments or answers and google can't index it either.

Comment: You are right, I have edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
The two relationships (lets call them `ads` and `favs`) are completely independent both in the database and on the the Java side of things.

You just introduce a new attribute `favs` and map it as Many-To-Many.